# Mouse Indicators are overlapping in dojo chart

Tags: dojox.charting

I have a dojo chart with varies series and i add a mouse indicator for each series. Now when i am hovering the mouse on the chart then it is overlapping the mouse indicators.
What is the best way to solve this problem.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

When you create the Indicator, add the "offset" parameter. Your first offset should be 0, and then increase it by a set amount so that the next indicator is out of the way of the first.

```
//yOffset is the step size for the y offset. index initialized to 0.
var yOffset = 20;
var interactor = new Indicator(holder.chart, "default", {
    series: *your series goes here*,  
    offset: {x: 0, y: yOffset * index}, 
 });
 index += 1;
```